# Making 'Check out' option appear

Tags: commerce

I am using the Commerce module and Paypal WPS on Drupal 7. When logged in as Admin to my website on a product page I can see the 'Check out' link next to 'View Cart'. However, if I log out and select the same product the 'Check out' option is not there. All I can see is the shopping cart.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this issue by changing the permissions for the Checkout module. I went to People/Permissions/Checkout and enabled 'access checkout' for both anonymous and authenticated users. Previously it was just enabled for Administrator. Hope this helps anyone else with the same issue.